# Video on full screen in WebView

Tags: android, video, webview, fullscreen

can someone help me please? I want a simple method to just enable fullscreen on a video being played in my WebView by simple tapping the video two times or having the fullscreen mode icon in the video player.

Here what I have:

```
package com.orb.tvdroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Igor Lima on 29/06/2017.
 */
public class TVDroid extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView TVDroid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tv_droid);

        final Activity activity = this;

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#007f00")));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Espere o carregamento da página completar.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Em seguida, escolha um dos canais disponíveis para começar a transmissão.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final String link = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("Link");

        TVDroid = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.TVdroid);
        this.registerForContextMenu(TVDroid);
        WebSettings webSettings = TVDroid.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        TVDroid.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progresso) {
                activity.setTitle("TVDroid... " + progresso + "%");
                activity.setProgress(progresso * 100);
                if (progresso == 100)
                    activity.setTitle("TVDroid");
            }
        });

        TVDroid.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return true;
            }
        });



        TVDroid.loadUrl(link);
    }
}
```

I already looked into many solutions here, but many of them seems a bit too much for what I want to do. I dont want a full video player function, all I want is just being able to double tap the video player and set it on full screen on my app.

Thanks in advance.

Just did it guys, Thanks Vishal for your idea, here is the final onCreate:

```
    WebView TVDroid;
    ProgressDialog carregando;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        this.setTitle("TVDroid");

        carregando = new ProgressDialog(TVDroid.this);
        carregando.show();

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        final Activity activity = this;

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#007f00")));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Espere o carregamento da página completar.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Em seguida, escolha um dos canais disponíveis para começar a transmissão.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final String link = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("Link");

        TVDroid = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.TVdroid);
        TVDroid.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        TVDroid.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                TVDroid.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];"
                        + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                        "})()");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        TVDroid.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progresso) {
                carregando.setMessage("Carregando página: " + progresso + "%");
                activity.setProgress(progresso * 100);
                if (progresso == 100)

                    carregando.dismiss();
            }
        });

        TVDroid.loadUrl(link);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Create a new FullscreenActivity -

```
File -> New -> Activity -> FullscreenActivity
```

Copy your `TVDroid` activity code in to `FullscreenActivity`.

Comment: I dont want a full screen activity, just want the video to go fullscreen when double tap

Here is how the video is being shown in my app http://imgur.com/a/HFbje

Comment: did you try? functionality same as per your need only difference is single/multiple tap, you can change accordingly

Comment: I tried your method, it better than what I have, tho I tried to double tap the video to go fullscreen, but it won't work, instead, I have to rotate my phone to make the video bigger, but it not in fullscreen :/

Sorry, it been a while since my last Android app, and I'm very noobish right now haha :P

Comment: This is how the video is being played http://imgur.com/a/k5itX with your method (better than what I had) but the header of the site i'm playing the video from is cutting part of the player as you can see :/ thats why I want the video to be able to go fullscreen just like on their site.

Comment: I worked around your method, now I think I can do it if I'm able to remove the Header of the page when my WebView loads it. I'm using  the onPageFinished method, but i dont know the html stuff to remove it with javascript.

Comment: I think it won't do, I have to use the javascript to load the page inside the WebView without the header :/